# How to reverse an array is assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, macros, x86, masm

I'm trying to write a simple program that reverses an array. It almost works, well it works for the first half of the array anyway. The term in the middle is always "0" and then it returns to the pattern. For example, if I input: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, the output will be 10,9,8,7,6,0,6,5,4,3. The order of the program is basically this:

Call to ReverseArray:

```
 INVOKE ReverseArray,
 LENGTHOF array, SIZEOF array, TYPE array, OFFSET array
```

ReverseArray procedure (loops through the array and calls mSwap32):

```
ReverseArray PROC, 
    len:DWORD, s:DWORD, increment:DWORD,address:DWORD
    mov edx, OFFSET revArray 
    call WriteString
    mov edi, address
    mov esi, address
    add esi, s
    sub esi, TYPE array
    mov ecx, len
    shr ecx, 1
    L2:
        mSwap32 edi, esi 
        add edi, increment
        sub esi, increment
    loop L2
    ret
ReverseArray endp
```

mSwap32 Macro (is given two addresses to swap):

```
mSwap32 MACRO address1:REQ, address2:REQ
    mov edi, address1
    mov esi, address2
    mov eax, [esi]
    push eax
    mov eax, [edi]
    mov [esi], eax
    pop eax
    mov [edi], eax
ENDM
```

I'm fairly certain that the error is in mSwap32...I'm sure it is some small logical error I'm missing, but no matter how much I toy with it I can not figure it out. ??

Comment: And, when you single-step through your code with a debugger, what do you see? What? You *haven't* done that? I suggest you do so, it's debugging 101 :-)

Comment: I didn't ask you to look at the compiler (properly, assembler) output although you *should* understand each instruction in the code and what it does. I suggested you single step *through* the code with whatever debugger you have available to you and keep an eye on what happens to the registers and memory. The best way to understand the machine is to *be* the machine, or at least a somewhat less speedy variant of it :-)

Comment: Also `sub esi, TYPE array` is breaking the encapsulation of your function, you should be using `increment` since you may want to call said function with an array of different type. And, to be honest, if single-stepping did not help, you need to keep doing it until it *does* help - that is, after all, the whole point of learning assembly, so that you can understand how it works, and there's really no lower level you can usefully see. For example, have a look at (and post) the contents of all the registers you've set, at the point after the `shr` instruction. Then again just before the `loop`.

Comment: Then, since you think the problem is in `mSwap32`, the prudent thing to do would be to examine registers and appropriate memory following *each* instruction in that function.

Comment: Pay attention to the size of the type of your data when calculating the end pointer to use.

Comment: I think you can also swap memory *without* that lengthy function, simply by doing `push [esi]; push [edi]; pop [esi]; pop [edi]`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError , I'm not sure what you mean by the end pointer? paxdiablo , please stop commenting essentially lecturing me and telling me to figure it out myself. This is also part of an assignment on how to use macros, so the "lengthy function" is not optional

Comment: I mean the value in `esi` at the beginning - make sure it actually points to the end of the array before the loop.

Comment: FWIW, the swap macro looks okay to me, assuming the array elements are 32-bit values.

Comment: No, it's a WORD array, and I've been calling the macro: mSwap32  edi, esi . I see the problem now, but how would I fix that?

Comment: I am not telling you to figure it out yourself, I am telling you *how* to figure it out yourself. But, since you seem to just want it solved instead of taking advice on how to do the work yourself, I'll make no further comment.

Answer (score 1):

> it's a WORD array

With this crucial piece of information we can solve the problems. LENGTHOF will be 10 (as before), SIZEOF will now be 20 and TYPE will now be 2.

```
ReverseArray PROC, 
    len:DWORD, s:DWORD, increment:DWORD,address:DWORD
    mov edx, OFFSET revArray 
    call WriteString
    mov edi, address
    mov esi, address
    add esi, s
    sub esi, increment  ;Better not refer to the actual array here!
    mov ecx, len
    shr ecx, 1
    L2:
        mSwap32 edi, esi 
        add edi, increment
        sub esi, increment
    loop L2
    ret
ReverseArray endp
```

and the macro:

```
mSwap32 MACRO address1:REQ, address2:REQ
    mov edi, address1
    mov esi, address2
    mov ax, [esi]
    push eax
    mov ax, [edi]
    mov [esi], ax
    pop eax
    mov [edi], ax
ENDM
```

Shorter and still using a macro:

```
mSwap32 MACRO address1:REQ, address2:REQ
    mov edi, address1
    mov esi, address2
    mov ax, [esi]
    xchg ax, [edi]
    mov [esi], ax
ENDM
```